# Is there a mechanism to detect sock-puppets?

Tags: discussion

Even a simplest one? Say, if some user gets all their downvotes reverted pretty fast, no matter how old and inactive the question is. And, I bet, the only activity of a Good Samaritan is to support this particular user. Can't this enthusiast programmer's site employ some AI to discourage fraud?

Comment: Yes, there is one.

Comment: Well, I hope it worked someday.

Comment: Can I ask what prompted the question? Anything specific?

Comment: If you think you have found a user running sock puppets please flag one of their posts for moderator attention using the "other" option. There is a mechanism, but it doesn't hurt to have have backup from real users from time to time.

Comment: @RichardScriven reputation is shared between SO and Meta SO accounts

Comment: I'm not sure where y'all got 'unclear what you're asking' here - it's pretty clear (IMHO).

Comment: related: [Voting rings - how to handle organized groups upvoting each other?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322114/839601)

Answer (score 64):

There's actually several. As others noted, we don't disclose the mechanics of the algorithms at work, but they're pretty good at spotting folks that cast votes for the wrong reasons. Votes in either direction should be based on the merits of the post, *not* the person that wrote it.

A process runs each day that looks for what we call targeted voting patterns, and in many causes, automatically reverses the votes. Beyond that, moderators are able to see reports of suspicious voting patterns and investigate further, often escalating the most 'interesting' cases to developers, who can see every vote in the system (and invalidate them if needed).

Sure, it's *possible* to guess the mechanics of the fraud detection stuff and sneak below it, but with all of the humans also paying close attention, it's *extremely* difficult to do it for long. Some have done it, we've uncovered voting rings in the past that spanned *hundreds* of accounts across tens of sites (yes, that many) - but we did end up catching them (full credit to Bill The Lizard for unraveling that one).

As with any system, nothing is perfect - so if you are *certain* that you're being targeted and have not seen the system reverse any votes, [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to have a look.

---

As an aside, I'm currently drafting a feature that will add 'just in time' help for folks that seem to be targeting posts by specific users in a measured amount of time. This is more to help people that just naturally feel inclined to vote for their friends avoid getting on the wrong side of a moderation notice, but it should also provide a stern enough warning to those that go on 'revenge' sprees. If you manage to trip it, you'll get something like this:

> Watch out, votes should be cast based on the technical merits of the post you're voting on, not to express you general approval or disapproval of their author. You've cast a noticeable amount of votes toward specific users recently, make sure you're voting for the right reasons, or your account might fall under scrutiny

.. or something to that effect, which needs to be deliberately dismissed. Still on the drawing board, but we need something like that.

Comment: I see. Daily basis is too short a term for getting any significant statistics.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Tim said that the post runs daily, not that it only looks at that day's data.

Comment: @YourCommonSense with all due respect, it's more than sufficient (given the way votes are stored and such) - running more than once a day would simply be too expensive. Every vote _in all states_ is recorded, so the system can even look at previously deleted votes. I can't give much more of a hint than that but, it could run weekly and be equally effective, just not timely, if that makes sense.

Comment: By voting do you mean up/down? Or all including close/delete/undelete?

Comment: Will the warning you're talking about still come with an automated vote reversal? To prevent someone gaming the system with it?

Comment: @bjb568 Up / down.

Comment: @thegrinner This would be in addition to the automatic stuff, think 'guard rails'

Comment: Oh good. I like to serial VTC people when seeing that not just one question but all their questions are bad.

Comment: @TimPost: What should we do if we come across a sock puppet ring? I am active on a certain tag, and am pretty sure of a sock puppet ring because of certain behaviours which a fixed group of accounts exhibit. I avoid all questions and answers posted by that ring, and ignore their activities. But after reading your answer that community members have earlier helped in detecting such rings, I would like to know your suggestion.

Comment: @Payeli Flag it for moderator attention (select the 'other' reason) - they'll get us involved if it's warranted.

Comment: @TimPost, can you show some stats on how many such sockpuppets are caught on a weekly/monthly basis.

Comment: Definitely you guys need to post stories some day of the shenanigans you've seen. Would like to read about that voting ring.

Comment: Speaking of patterns, what happens I upvote 10 _good_ answers by a specific user. Do these votes revert because there is a pattern?

Comment: @SalmanA I can't say for sure (since I obviously don't know implementation details), but my understanding was that over a longer period of time, if you happened to actually see and upvote a total of 10 posts from the same user, then that's fine. Just don't, you know, do all 10 upvotes at once.

Comment: @SalmanA You're describing a situation where you likely landed on someone's profile, and then began digging through and voting on their contributions. We _strongly_ discourage that (in either direction) because it's getting very close to voting for a _user_, even though there's clear technical merit to vote on. The algorithm might, or might not trip - and I can't tell you why it would or wouldn't, I can just say that there's a good chance that some of the votes might be silently invalidated.

Comment: @TimPost Pingback to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295335/3989608

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is one. The details of it are kept fairly secret, to keep people from finding ways to circumvent it.

Comment: It seems this watchdog is of very primitive specimen, aiming primarily to stupid serial upvoting, not occasional but regular "karma corrections"

Answer (score 3):

The serial voting reversal script is the only algorithm that is public to some extent, but that is not the real defense against sock puppets and vote fraud. Anyone that observes it for a bit can avoid triggering it, the script deals with the easy and completely obvious situations automatically, which saves a lot of time the moderators and SE would have to spend on them otherwise. It is not meant to be unbeatable, it just handles the boring routine stuff.

There are some other algorithms that are not public, but even those are not the important part. In the end, what a user committing vote fraud faces is an actual human being examining their record (if you accept the theory that the moderators are human, which is sometimes disputed). Dealing with vote fraud is not automated, there are some tools to help but the bulk of the work is done manually by moderators. You don't have to trick an algorithm to commit vote fraud, but you actually have to beat a moderator that has a rather large box of tools available to investigate vote fraud. Most of the tools are stuff that someone thinking a bit about the problem would easily come up with, but there are a few I don't think users actually expect.