# Can the system detect and handle multi-votes from accounts that are friends?

Tags: support, downvotes

What happened is that one of my co-worker posted an answer, after that someone else posted an answer too in the same question, downvoted co-worker's answer, and commented `-1 [...]`; I will save stuff here. What the co-worker did is asking a few others to downvote that one's answer, until he asked me and I explained why this behaviour is unhealthy for the site and cancelled all of those votes immediately.

My question is whatever the system could handle and cancel all of those votes, without me being there explaining?

I am almost sure that it can't do such thing; so I thought of two suggestions:

1. This one is a bit odd at first, but has high chance of working: Remove the downvote's -2 and keep the penalty to the downvoter, it will decrease the actual value of downvoting, but still it will lead to answer ban when needed; what will happened is that they will downvote all of his last 3-... answers to activate answer ban (To cause damange.), but what will happen is reversal of serial votes. (They don't have chance to decrease rep nor activating answer ban.)
2. All of those that agreed to the co-worker to use their account had 125..500 rep; how about zeroing similar users downvote's -2? I think it's a valid decision, because they are less presenting the site then others with 5K+\10K+ rep.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259949/is-there-a-mechanism-to-detect-sock-puppets

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/140505

Answer (score 3):

While some parts of handling vote fraud are automated, the main defense against any abuse of the voting system is manual intervention by moderators and SE employees.

If people coordinate vote fraud on a larger scale, this will inevitably be detected at some point. And then you have an actual person investigating the situation in detail, not any automatic mechanism that could be easily tricked.

I don't see any need to change anything here, any automated mechanism I could imagine would be likely to either miss most situations, or cause too many false positives. Handling the more unusual cases manually is still the best option in my opinion.