# Does SO prevent upvotes bot?

Tags: discussion, upvotes

I was wondering if Stack Overflow has some sort of script or check to prevent a user incrementing their own reputation using another account. For example using an upvote-bot that automatically upvotes some/all the question/answers of a particular SO account:

1. BOB's account has 100 questions and 1000 answers
2. BOB has another account with enough rep to upvote: JOHN
3. BOB uses JOHN's account to upvote all BOB's questions/answers in order to increase BOB's reputation.

Is there something to prevent this?

Are there any checks on users upvotes?

Comment: Note that JOHN would need to have enough reputation first to be able to vote..

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep, I was counting that already :) question updated. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Yes - There is a system which prevents any user (not just a second account) to upvote questions / answers based on account only. These upvotes will be reverted and reputation will be restored to their original state.

Keep in mind that you cannot upvote with new accounts as well, you will need to earn reputation first.

Comment: Thanks, is there a documentation about that?

Comment: Information about specific mechanics to prevent abuse are not disclosed, so not really. However this answer is a little bit more in-depth: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259952/4274852