# Strange reputation change for a user

Tags: discussion, reputation, serial-voting

I hope this is the right place to notify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2824801/dal%c4%b1m-%c3%87epi%c3%a7?tab=reputation) user who has a strange reputation change by gaining **200** reputation in about 5 minutes with an upvote on 20 different answers. I know that there is a service which runs to check for strange reputation change but there could be someone (human) maybe a moderator who can check these upvotes? I don't want to discriminate no one but if these are illegitimate votes, it's not OK.

Comment: The detection script runs every night. This is so obvious it will be taken care of. Flag one of this user's posts in ~24h if it hasn't been corrected.

Comment: That will certainly be caught by the serial voting script.

Comment: It looks weird to see that the rep graph on the Activity tab has infinite slope! (Maybe this is common and I ovserved it for the first time)

Comment: Ok, so if I flag for *moderator intervention* on one of his posts this will be ok? The first (and last) time I fagged for *moderator intervention* they answered me something like "don't do this" D:

Comment: You might want to check if more is wrong...

Comment: @CliffBurton: don't flag _now_. Wait until 24h have passed. There's no emergency.

Comment: @Mat: Yes I meant to do this after 24h. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Comment: @Mixcels: I think it happens because he earned **346rep** in 1 year and 8 months and then **200rep** (4/7 of his previous rep and 4/11 of his total rep now) in 5 minutes

Comment: Looks like the rep change has all gone with a "user was removed" explanation.

Comment: @MartinSmith: so apparently all of those up votes were from the same 'user'. Pity his Mortarboard badge remains. I used to hope to earn it some day (legally) but this is kind of a downer.

Comment: @Jongware this has been a long standing issue except if clear evidence is found of sock puppetry http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126363/145673

Comment: Looks like it happened again.

Comment: @Jongware Go bounty hunting. It worked for me.

Comment: @MartinSmith: to be clear, the sockpuppet (voter) user was removed, and the upvotes cancelled, but this user himself wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite clearly a second account (either by them or a friend) serial up voting their posts.

```
-200    22:22   removed User was removed (learn more)
```

This has been reversed but their badge still remains.

*Afterthought*

Possibly could have been a serial up vote by someone wanting to "thank" them for an answer they have posted

Comment: Either by him or a friend? One moment... just looking for 'Matt' and upvoting on 200 of his posts.

Comment: @Greenflow: Actually only *20* of his posts! ;)

Comment: Judging huh.. How do you know if it is him or his friend? How about this - Some user who found one of his posts extremely useful and became so happy and wanted to give him some reps and badge? possibility right? In fact i had received similar serial up voting once (which obviously i did not do)...

Comment: @PSL look at the time stamp. all those 20 votes have been cast within 4 mins. You cant read 20 posts in 4 mins. One should not cast vote because he likes that person. Instead votes should be cast because the posts were helpful.

Comment: @SanthanSalai And helpful posts might already have high upvotes and even marked as an answer. Someone just passing by a good answer by an user, could upvote already upvoted answers of that user. So, not necessarily he is a friend, or a sock puppet.

Comment: Agree with @Greenflow. Many of us have probably been serially upvoted, and suggesting that we have any part in it is inappropriate.

Comment: @Greenflow By "a friend" meaning someone he works with/knows, not just an "internet friend" :)

Comment: @RetoKoradi Quite right you do see the cases where people serial upvote to "thank" you, but i dont think any of his answers merit that but i will mention this in my answer

Comment: I think we're missing the point. The thing is, if serially upvoting is bad, the problem is serailly upvoting, not being serially upvoted. Plus, it's 200 rep. If I find a friend in SO I'll probably go Through their answers sooner or later, possibly upvoting lots because I agree with their way of thinking (we're friends after all). If this is bad, this should be better explained, because it's a hell of a nice way to interact with friends, much like serially liking facebook posts from your closest friends, which lots of people do, especially when it's someone you admire or feel grateful towards.

Comment: Fernando, etc. There's simply **A POLICY** on this site that you are not allowed to "serial upvote" someone. I used to do it all the time, as it's the **absolutely obvious way** to thank/reward someone who writes an amazing answer. (Unknown to me, all my "serial upvotes" were reversed anyway!!)  This site is not "run by the government" or something. It's simply a business like any other, which some people set up so as to be able to make money to buy diapers & food for their kids. It's **their policy** and that's just life. It surely doesn't matter that much: take it as it is, or don't use!

Comment: @SanthanSalai That is how it happens.. :) Serial voters just want to give some thank votes, they don't have to read it. Open one vote on it, go to the next one...till they meet their goal. But nobody is suggesting that it is a good thing. Comments on this post has been towards a different point not on whether it is good or bad (which is an obvious one).

Comment: (It's simply a "prosumption" business, like any of many others, many of the large businesses of our day. Again when I stumbled on to the "serial voting - it's not allowed!" policy at first I wasted ten minutes asking "why?" etc - but it's just a policy. Really I'd just forget it and enjoy the site, which is what I do. If you don't like the policy, don't use the site I guess.  For example, another "prosumption" site like this is "trip advisor".  I learned of a policy on their I don't like .. so I stopped contributing content there. It's your choice.

Comment: Whereas when I learned about the utterly-bonkers "no serial voting!!!" policy on this site, i was bemused and then said to myself, oh who cares, and I still contribute free content here.  That's prosumption -- it's your choice to use the site!  Personally I would probably suggest, no matter how totally ridiculous the "no serial voting!!" policy is, just forget it and enjoy the site.)

Comment: What's the problem with a prohibition on serial voting?  The reason I love StackOverflow, and the reason that I will pick it over any other site when I search for the answer to a question, is that it has--by orders of magnitude--less crap answers to sift though than any other resource on the internet.   The "no serial voting" policy helps keep this quality in place:  valid and useful answers are bubbled up more reliably than with any other crowdsourced site I know of.    So I won't argue with what clearly works.

Answer (score 11):

> maybe a moderator that can check these upvotes?

It is well explained in Help Center about [Reputation & Moderation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed):

> If such a voting pattern continues to happen between two users
>   mutually or from one user towards another, or otherwise falls outside
>   of normal voting patterns, moderators and/or developers may
>   investigate the matter; intentionally voting merely to reduce or
>   inflate another user's reputation is considered abuse.

The system is capable of detecting such voting abuse and considers these votes to be invalid and removes them.

Having said that, there could be two cases:

- A user finding a user's great answer and visiting all of their posts to upvote them.
- Sock puppets

No matter the cause, this sort of systematic targeted voting is not considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.

The serial voting reversal script handles the most of the routine stuff, however, as @Tim Post said [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259949/is-there-a-mechanism-to-detect-sock-puppets) -- with any system, nothing is perfect. If you find that system did not detect a pattern, then you could [contact the Support Team](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and they would take care of it.

Comment: I have in the past found highly-qualified users working in the same domain I was seeking answers in...with a coherent answering style, and a tendency to explain not just how, but why. Are you saying that (despite how SO encourages me to thumbs up when I find stuff useful), if I follow through to their profile and check out their other answers and upvote them, they might get flagged?

Comment: @Fox - not if you only do that for a few.  However, if you go through a large number of a user's Q/As from their profile then, yes, there's a chance _your_ votes will be reversed.

Comment: @WilliamPrice Thanks. My intention was just just ask if the flagging... and  moderation system was robust enough to take this scenario into account... which may be a common response from a user who, teaching themselves something new, comes across a user answering common gotchas and saving him days of debugging.

Comment: @Fox Yes, that could be considered serial upvoting. The exact heuristics that trigger the detection are intentionally not published. But the script does not know your intentions. Even if you actually only upvote posts that you really believe *deserve* an upvote, it could still be flagged as a suspicious pattern, and reverted. So going through a users profile and upvoting multiple answers is not encouraged.