# Mediocre answer immediately upvoted

Tags: discussion, voting, voting-fraud

This has happened to me the second time in a week, so I thought I'd reach out to see your experience. Basically, I ask a question that receives and answer in a few hours, and within minutes, the answer is upvoted. These are niche question, with views in the lower teens, with sketchy answers that are clearly lacking in addressing what was explicitly asked. From the way it happened, I'd be tempted to say this is either people with two/several accounts voting for themselves or a bunch of people doing favours.

But I know there are safeguard against serial voters, hate/chain voting and voting rings, so I am cautious. But this is slightly different in that there is only a single vote - almost as though to soften / favourably dispose subsequent visitors to upvote the top / most active / highest ranking answer at the time. For popular topics, it quickly gets evened out, but for smaller topics, I am finding it a nuisance that I need to explicitly add a comment and say this answer is insufficient in such and such and does not or only partly addresses what I would like to know.

Question: is there a way to figure out if the first answers by a person a consistently upvoted by the same account(s) within a short period of time?

Comment: Also see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259949/is-there-a-mechanism-to-detect-sock-puppets).

Comment: I have read the answers both @MarounMaroun and Martijn suggested and they give a solution to the problem, not and answer to my question. A subtle but important difference. To be more specific, I know I can flag and answer, and explain this weird situation to a mod, but: #1 I do not want to cast the shadow of doubt regarding the integrity  of a fellow member without a fairly solid ground for my claim. #2 I want to know if I can test my hypothesis about this. So Martijn, could you please reopen the question for me? Thank you.

Comment: For those who want to know: the answer is actually no. Users cannot be reverse-engineered from their votes on particular answers. I ran a few errands on https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/614297 to see if I can prove my hypothesis right or wrong, but the user ID is not shown in the database for particular votes. I added a few lines to explain the basic reasoning in the SQL.